# Why does one css grid resize but the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I have two grids of 2x2 images, one with title bars over the images and one without.  The grid without title bars resizes to fit the screen, which is what I want, but the grid with title bars keeps the images the same size regardless of the size of the window.  What am I doing wrong here?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './image-grid.scss';

export function ImageGrid({images})
{
    return (
        <div className="image-grid">
            {images.map((i) => <div className="image-container">
                    <img className="image" src={i.image}></img>
                    <div className={i.tag ? "tag" : "empty-tag"}>
                        <div className="text">{i.tag}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

```css
.image-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
}

.empty-tag {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.tag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 70%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    height: 28%;

    .text {
        padding-left: 20px;
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: I converted your code into an snippet. Please add some HTML and fix the JavaScript to make it working.